# Retrieve Data from Sqllite DB between Two dates android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I retrieve data between two dates some how it get correct result and some how it output empty listview  when i select dates with month it work properly but when i select dates between more than one month it output empty listview below is my codes

here i declare the variable in DB class

```
public static final String EX_RowID = "_id";
public static final String EX_Cattype = "Ecattype";
public static final String EX_Date = "Ecdate";
public static final String EX_Price = "Ecprice";
public static final String EX_Type = "itype";
```

creat table statement

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Food_TABLE +"(" +
                EX_RowID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                EX_Cattype + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                EX_Date + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                EX_Price + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                EX_Type + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );"
                );

    }
```

enter data Method

```
 public long ExEntry(String Ecatgtype, String Edate, String Eprice, String Eitype) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(EX_Cattype, Ecatgtype);
cv.put(EX_Date, Edate );
cv.put(EX_Price, Eprice);
cv.put(EX_Type, Eitype);
return ourdatabase.insertOrThrow(Food_TABLE, null, cv);
 }
```

here i access the ExEntry Method

```
ExMgDB Expentry = new ExMgDB(ADD_EX.this);
    Expentry.open();
    Expentry.ExEntry(cate, date, price, itype);
    Expentry.close();
```

here i am facing the problem between these two dates variables

```
 public Cursor CstmRpot(String fd, String td) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[] {EX_RowID,EX_Cattype, EX_Date, EX_Price, EX_Type };
Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Date  + " BETWEEN '" + fd + "'  
 AND '" + td + "'" , null, null, null, null);
if (c != null) {

       c.moveToFirst();

      }
return c;

}
```

i access it like below

```
 CustemRpt dbcs = new CustemRpt();    
Cursor cursor = CstDB.CstmRpot(frmdate,tondate);
```

Comment: How are you storing the date values in Ecdate field?
If you use a string field to store dates, be sure that ordering as string is also valid for the corresponding date. To achive this, you should store the dates as yyyymmdd

Comment: so when i change the formate so what do you think it will be correct result

Comment: what do you mean by ordering

Comment: to get a range of data between two dates, the database engine needs to get an ordered list, isn't it?

Comment: i did your method but the problem exist

Comment: Please add some examples for `fd` and `td`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559984/retrieve-out-of-range-data-between-two-dates-android 
you can check my question now copy paste above link sir

Comment: @IHateErrors Referenceing code from other questions is a bad habbit, since everything that is needed to answer your question and to understand your problem should be in your question. This way others that might have the same or a similar problem can benefit of it as well, even if the other question is deleted for some reason. Many people are making affords to help finding solutions to problems on this platform. Many people won't help you if they first have to search through multiple links to get to know your problem!

Comment: what do you think if i convert the string to date and save it as an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major solutions. All solutions have in common, that the column containing the date has to be ordered somehow. If this order is destroyed your data is corrupt and your queries cannot return the expected results!

**1. Save your Dates as `INTEGER` in your database and use a method to map Dates to a number:**

A possible way is to use `Date.getTime ()` to map Dates to numbers, but there are many others. Important is that

1. equal dates get the same number and
2. that a date that is after another date gets a bigger number.

This way ordering will be correct for sure.
To achieve this with `Java.util.Date.getTime() you only have to set the time to 0:00:00:000 if you want to store date only.

For example:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + Food_TABLE +"(" +
    EX_RowID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    EX_Cattype + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    EX_Date + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
    EX_Price + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
    EX_Type + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );"

private static String dateOnly(java.util.Date d) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // locale-specific
    cal.setTime(d);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return Long.toString(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}

public Cursor CstmRpot(java.util.Date fd, java.util.Date td) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{EX_RowID,EX_Cattype, EX_Date, EX_Price, EX_Type };
    Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Date + " > " + dateOnly (fd) + " AND " + EX_Date + " < " + dateOnly(td), null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

If you don't use different timezones the `dateOnly(java.util.Date d)` can be optimized.
Of course you can also use JODA-time.

**2. Save your Dates as `TEXT`**

If you choose this method your queries that are comparing the date-column are going to be a bit slower, but the entries in the database are human readable which doesn't have t be the case with method 1.
`TEXT`-columns are ordered with [BINARY](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) by default, which means `memcmp()` is used to compare the values and to determine which value is greater or if the values are equal. (Remember `x BETWEEN a AND b` means `x <= a AND x >= b`.) 
You can examine the work of `memcmp()` with this function [memcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/).

To ensure you get the right results you have to ensure the following:

1. All date-values in your database have to have the same text length.
2. All date-values in your database have to be in the same Format. The bigger date-parts (year) have to be before the smaller date-parts (month).
3. All Parameters for date-values in queries have to follow these rules too.

A possible date-format may look like this: `yyyy-MM-dd` (for example `2014-02-04` or `2000-12-24`).

**Advices**

- Use [android.widget.DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) instead of `Edittext` for getting dates as input.
- Never use any texts you got from user inputs directly in your query, but validate them before (see [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).
- Read some articles about how Strings are compared.

Comment: i like your code sir but your dateOnly() method i can't understand

Comment: It combines three functions: 1. truncating the time from `java.util.Date` so that it is date only 2. converting it to milliseconds since 1.1.1970. 3.converting it to `String` which is what you need to create the statement. It's just one example of how to store a date in sqlite. The other answers about sorting string are also correct and depending on your exact needs I'd use the one or the other solution or just another form of representing a date as a number.

Comment: also my EX_Date is type of string

Comment: also i use the .get(dayofmonth), .get(monthofyear) and .get(year) method and i set these to edittext.set(year + " - " + (month + 1) + " - " + year ); year ,monthofyear and dayofmonth is my separate variables sir how i convert it to millisecond from string

Comment: @IHateErrors Please add this code to your question as it is relevant. You have to make sure that year always has 4 digits and that month and day both always have two digits.

Comment: AlexS please check my this question you will undersood what i am doing wrong   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559984/retrieve-out-of-range-data-between-two-dates-android/21562231?noredirect=1#21562231

Comment: @IHateErrors You can store your dates either as `INTEGER` or as `TEXT`, see my edits. Your problem seems to be, that you have malformatted date-values in your database, because you didn't take care, that the date-string always has the same length.

Comment: what do you think if i convert the string to date and save it as an integer

Comment: @IHateErrors See my post. I tells you everything you need.

Comment: i did it my date save as number(convert string to date and filter to millisecond) but i got another issue i want to display this date in list view like date but it save as number like 124012311 like this

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT * FROM "your table" WHERE date BETWEEN "from date" AND "to date";`

Answer (score 0):

you need to store date inform of yyyy-mm-dd and then use this method simply call getWeekData(start_date, end_date);

```
public Object getWeekData(String start_date, String end_date) {
        if (!mDataBase.isOpen())
            openDataBase();

        Object data = new Object ();
        // Select All Query
        String query = (String) ("Select * from " + TBL_NAME 
                + " where " + (COL_DATE + " between '" + start_date + "' AND '" + end_date + "'"));
        Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //get data over here
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: i apply my method same like you but i also get the data out of my range

Answer (score 0):

we have Two solution for this question

one is we need to convert date and time into milliseconds, and take long data type in

Sqllite database and save values(converted date and time). And the write query like "SELECT

data, start_date, end_date from tablename WHERE start_date > end_date".

Second way is you need to save start and end date+time(yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) in string format

in Sqllite database, and you need to query like this,

"SELECT datetime_start,datetime_end FROM tablename WHERE(( DATETIME(atetime_start) >=

DATETIME ("+"'"+entry_start_time+"'"+")" +" AND DATETIME(datetime_end) < DATETIME

("+"'"+entry_end_time+"'"+")); .

Comment: i have only one date colomn and i define it as a string in database and also i get data from date picker when user click on edittext and it contain three variables and i don't need time i only concern with date

Comment: when i left my colomn as string so what i do next

Comment: you need to maintain two columns start and end date. Then only you can query the db. or else you need to write a simple logic like, first you need to get all data from db , and then you need to filter by using code(if condition)