# convert mellisecond to date and populate in listView using cursor

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, date

i want to retrieve data my date colomn save date in mellisecond now i want to retrieve this mellisecond and covert to date and populate in listview using simplecursorAdapter how can i do this below is my code

```
   String sd = currdate.get(Calendar.YEAR) +"-"+ currmonth +"-"+ 
   currdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  

    Date sDcur = null;
    try {
        sDcur = sf.parse(sd);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    long ldcur = sDcur.getTime();

    Cursor cursor = lstDb.CurrentExp(ldcur);

      String[] columns = new String[] {
        ExMgDB.EX_RowID,
        ExMgDB.EX_Cattype,
        ExMgDB.EX_Date,
        ExMgDB.EX_Price,
        ExMgDB.EX_Type

       };

      int dateColumn = R.id.txtexdate; 
      Date d = new Date(dateColumn); 
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
      String date = dateFormat.format(d);
      Log.i("Mytag2", date.toString());
      long ldate = Long.valueOf(date); // on this line my logcate show exception   
  like java.long.numberfomate exception

      int[] to =  new int[]{
          R.id.txtexid,
          R.id.txtexcat,
          (int) ldate, 
          R.id.txtexprice,
          R.id.txtexitype
      };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.emtolst, 
                cursor, 
                columns, 
                to,
                0);

              ListView listView = (ListView) 
findViewById(android.R.id.list);
              // Assign adapter to ListView
              listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

here is my query

```
public Cursor CurrentExp(long ldcur) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[] {EX_RowID,EX_Cattype, EX_Date, EX_Price, EX_Type };
Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Date + "='" + ldcur + "'", null,   
    null, null, null);


if (c != null) {

       c.moveToFirst();

      }
return c;


}
```

Comment: too much code, but I guess the `MMM` in the date format does place december before january.

Comment: what kind of value does that `fdate.getText().toString()` gives you ? also, why do you save the dates as text?

Comment: no sir the problem with just i add the Date as string thats why it get out of range data now i am confuse what i did with it

Comment: On second though, you probably have texts such as `2014-1-1`, which cannot really compare to texts such as `2014-10-10, since the comparison here will end up comparing `-` and `0`.

Comment: fdate is get string type of data i use date as text from beggining and  i don't have any idea for the date what its type to save

Comment: are you, now? Well I am terribly sorry. I will hurry up and serve you, then. No, seriously, what would you expect ?

Comment: nota : you have already asked this question yesterday and there was an answer already...

Comment: i am confused that what i did with my code sir

Comment: the other question said that store your date as long how can i store it when i use three variable in sroring date like edittext.set(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

Comment: ever heard of timestamps ? (hint: not like stamps for time travelers.)

Comment: i haven't concern with timestamps i need only date and i am confuse about my ADD_EX class in my question in this class what i did with date

Comment: you don't see how 2014-1-1 and 2014-12-31 cannot be compared as date given that they are strings ? do you know how string comparison is performed?

Comment: hmmmm what can i do now

Comment: use longs to store your date, I thought that had been said already.

Comment: @njzk2 i edit my question how can i get out from ban please help me

Comment: @Kevin Panko i edit my question so how can i get out from ban

Comment: @ntalbs i edit my question so how can i get out from ban

Comment: @GrlsHu i edit my question so how can i get out from ban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the dates in the SQL database as text strings, but then asking SQL to return values between to limits and expecting it to interpret those limits as dates when it hasn't been told that they are dates and wouldn't know how to interpret the text format as a date if it did know they were dates.

Use Date.getTime() to convert the dates to long values and store those in SQL as numbers.  Similarly convert your start and end times to long values, and ask SQL to return records between those values.  Any time you need to convert what is stored in SQL back into a user-friendly date, use the Date(long value) constructor and pass it the number that SQL gives you.

Comment: you mean to change the Date field to integer and get the value from edit text as an integer or long and convert it to millisecond with the help of caleder instanse after that store to DB

Answer (score 0):

Use a Date column instead of a Text column and use placeholders `?` in the query instead of putting the values in the query directly like

```
ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Date  + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", new String[]{firstDate, lastDate}, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: please refer example of my query with placeholder

Comment: this is not an answer. It does not address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `db_date` is the date in your table, `arg_begins_on & arg_ends_on` are the date arguments that act like boundary dates passed to the query, then:

---

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE (db_date > :arg_ends_on ) OR (db_date < :arg_begins_on);
```

Comment: i have only one Date colomn i guess that my problem i understand to njzk2

Comment: now, this query will solve your problem. please mark it as solved, if it helps you.

Comment: sorry sir you don't pick my problem

Comment: i want to fetch the data between two dates (fromdate and todate) my query is work correct but it fetch out of range data also