# Inserting a Date in SQLite and then compare for a specific interval

Tags: android, sqlite

I have on table which contains a Date column as "Time DATE" now I am using content Values to insert data into it.
Content Values takes input as `cv.put(String Key,String Value)` now how do I insert a **Date** Data in it and after insertion when i insert next time it should check for interval like **5 min before and after** and if condition fails some message will be thrown.
The only Problem is I can not store Date as Date. I need some information how I can achieve that.

```
public long InsertDetails (String name, String Item, int amount, Date Time){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues ();``
        CV.put(Dbhelper.Name,  name );
        CV.put(Dbhelper.Item, Item);
        CV.put(Dbhelper.Amount, amount);
        CV.put(Dbhelper.DATE, String.valueOf(Time));//this take (String,String)
        long id=db.insert(Dbhelper.TableName,null,CV)
        return id;
       }
```

After insertion i can not compare the time values with the next insertion value as the values stored are in string.
How do i achieve it ,Note before Inserting I need to compare time interval also.

Comment: Store date as `long` in SQLIte Database. Using  `Time.getTime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert your `DATE` to milliseconds before storing it to Database
2. At the time of comparison convert the String to long using:

   `Long.parseLong(stringTime);`
3. Compare them both.

Hope this works.

Comment: So for each time when I have to compare i will have to pull all the data out convert  and compare each and then insert Right??

Comment: yes. This will be easier. Then storing date and compare. You will be more accurate with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529351/retrieve-data-from-sqllite-db-between-two-dates-android) will help you 
Save your Dates as INTEGER in your database and use a method to map Dates to a number or you can save it as long in Database before that you need to convert your date value into millisecond when you convert it to millisecond it will give you appropriate result in calculation i mean when you want it to compare it between two dates.